# Where is manifest_pb2 inside session_bundle?

Tags: tensorflow-serving

I am trying to export a previously trained model (pb) to be used for serving
using the following snippet

```
from tensorflow_serving.session_bundle import exporter
def create_graph():
        """Creates a graph from saved GraphDef file and returns a saver."""
        # Creates graph from saved graph_def.pb.
        with tf.gfile.FastGFile(modelFullPath, 'rb') as f:
            graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
            graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
            _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')

def export():
        print 'Exporting trained model to', export_path
        saver = tf.train.Saver(sharded=True)
        model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(saver)
        signature = exporter.classification_signature(input_tensor=x, scores_tensor=y)
        model_exporter.init(sess.graph.as_graph_def(),default_graph_signature=signature) 
        model_exporter.export(export_path, tf.constant(FLAGS.export_version), sess)
        print 'Done exporting!'
```

However the manifest_pb2 in exporter.py is not Found. 
Am I missing something fundamental in this approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`manifest_pb2.py` is generated from `manifest.proto` when the session_bundle is built using bazel. On Mac I installed TensorFlow using pip3 and the file is located at `/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle/manifest_pb2.py`.

Follow the steps at https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html for your platform and it should fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right , I figured it out later. Thanks.